# Derivative of logarithmic function

Tags: derivatives

> If the function $f(x)=\log_{2x}x^2$ is given, what is $f'(4)$?

I tried to use the formula for derivative of logarithm but here the base is $2x$, so it made me confused.

Note that the answer is $1/(18\ln 2)$.

Comment: Are you expecting that people will fix your questions all the time?

Comment: @Kaster Sorry if I made a mistake but what do you mean by fixing?

Comment: I think he's talking about your lack of math formatting.

Comment: @guest I meant your inability to learn how to format math after asking 4 questions.

Comment: @guest - I've fixed up the question, please look at the formatting so you can learn how to do it yourself next time.

Comment: You are completely right. Sorry for being lazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Note that:
$$\log_b a = \frac{\ln a}{\ln b}$$
Now you can use the formula for the derivative of a fraction.